# Using Promise.all in TypeScript to pass values to next handler in chain

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, es6-promise

In JavaScript in can sometimes be useful to use `Promise.all` to re-use some bit of data in a chain of asynchronous operations like so:

```
logMeIn()
.then(token => {
  return Promise.all([
    token,
    fetchProfile(token)
  ])
})
.then(([token, profile]) => {
  return getAvatar(token, {userId: profile.id})
})
// etc...
```

As we can see, the second `then` resolver needs the result of the first resolver but also still requires the `token`. One way would be to nest the second `then` call inside the first but this can get ugly and in a long chain it's no better then the callback hell promises where designed to mitigate.

Using `Promise.all()` allows us to re-use data from earlier resolvers and pass them down the chain.

This all works great but TypeScript flips out when you try and do this with errors like this:

> Argument of type '(string | Promise<Something>)[]' is not assignable
>   to parameter of type 'IterableShim<Something |
>   PromiseLike<Something>>'.   Types of property '"*es6-shim iterator*"'
>   are incompatible.
>       Type '() => IterableIteratorShim<string | Promise<Something>>' is not assignable to type '() => Iterator<Something |
>   PromiseLike<Something>>'.

Is there a way in TypeScript that the above can be done, preferably whilst retaining type safety?

Comment: Notice there are [many other solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28250680/1048572) for that general problem. Doesn't TypeScript already support `async`/`await`?

Comment: @Bergi It does, although this particular pattern would likely be supported when TypeScript gets [variadic types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to specify return type explicitly:

```
logMeIn()
    .then<[Token, Profile]>(token => Promise.all([token, fetchProfile(token)]))
    .then(([token, profile]) => getAvatar(token, { userId: profile.id }))
```